# Расставить знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Как в предложении  Отцу моему захотелось узнать, отчего потекла лодка. Аксаков пишется отчего.

Comment: Вопреки своему обыкновению даже не исправляю ошибки в вопросе — пусть все видят это ПОЗОРИЩЕ.

Answer (score 1):

"Отчего" пишется слитно — в значении "по какой причине". А при чем тут знаки препинания?

Answer (score 0):

Правильно так: *"Отцу моему захотелось узнать, отчего потекла лодка"*. Да, *"отчего"* пишется слитно, так как равно *"почему"*.